# WebGL Vertices Order

Tags: webgl, vertices

I am very new to WebGL and I have a question about the order of vertices. When creating a cube, the vertices will look like this:

```
var vertices = [
// Front face
-1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
 1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
 1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
-1.0,  1.0,  1.0,

// Back face
-1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
-1.0,  1.0, -1.0,
 1.0,  1.0, -1.0,
 1.0, -1.0, -1.0,

// Top face
-1.0,  1.0, -1.0,
-1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
 1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
 1.0,  1.0, -1.0,

// Bottom face
-1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
 1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
 1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
-1.0, -1.0,  1.0,

// Right face
 1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
 1.0,  1.0, -1.0,
 1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
 1.0, -1.0,  1.0,

// Left face
-1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
-1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
-1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
-1.0,  1.0, -1.0
];
```

Can I rearrange the order of these vertices into any order I want, or do they have to be in a certain order?

Comment: The answer that makes sense is that you can't mess with the order, but I'm assuming you have a demo or working version to play with. Why not try changing the order yourself and seeing what happens?

Answer (score 2):

Order of the vertices depends on the triangle culling paramaters and order in which the triangles are drawn.

Vertices that make up a triangle can be ordered in the right-hand or left-hand manner. Orientation of the triangle than describes the wait the normal of the triangle is pointing at. Read more [here](http://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-basic-lessons/lesson-9-ray-triangle-intersection/geometry-of-a-triangle/).

Depending on the option you select for the `gl.cullface( option )`, you have different culling of the triangles. So, that affects the vertices order.

Another important aspect to look after is order of the triangles/primitives that are drawn. You may have different requirements in your application, so may need to pre-order triangles that weer to be drawn, so that could also affect the order of the vertices. One such example is drawing transparent primitives. There are many issues with blending transparent primitives so need to take care. For more insightful direct example, read [this](http://learningwebgl.com/blog/?p=859).

Hope this helps you understand how the order of the vertices may or may not be important.